# Database failed to generate in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: asp.net, database, visual-studio-2008

I opened a project today and refreshed my connected database, but as I did I got this error:
Failed to generate a user instance of SQL Server due to a failure in starting the process for the user instance. The connection will be closed.

Before this I got a notice about a compatibility issue and had the option to get help online or to run anyways, bot choices lead me to the error above and my database would still not be connected.

The database worked fine before but I am not sure why I am getting this error now. Any solution to this problem would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We encountered this issue several times before. Here are your options:

You **delete the SQLExpress directory**, then restart the computer

C:\Documents and Settings\username\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Data\SQLEXPRESS directory

*or*

You select the **Local System Account** option in SQL Server properties

*or*

You replace the ConnectionString name in your web.config into **LocalSqlServer** if you are using a Membership Provider

This link [Problems with SQL Server Express user instancing and ASP.net Web Application Projects] (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2002980) would be able to explain it to you.

I hope it helps you.